# Comparison of power to multiplication in python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, optimization, data-structures

Read somewhere in my adventure in optimizing my mandelbrot program that if you are for example squaring something. Using the mandelbrot equation as the example that 
`z * z` is faster than `z**2`. Is this true, and if it is why is this so? Is it due to the fact that `z**2` still computes trivial cases such as 0?

Answer (score 2):

I am one of the people who have suggested the optimization and yes, it is true.  In the example below, squaring with `*` is over 3 times as fast as with `**2`.

```
from timeit import repeat
print(repeat('z*z', 'z=.54321 + .56789j'))
print(repeat('z**2', 'z=.54321 + .56789j'))
# prints
[0.07780417092306088, 0.05484807785182001, 0.05577646621573226]
[0.2081317598277747, 0.19060335713839965, 0.1913974058615736]
```

Since both operations give the same answer

```
>>> z*z
(-0.02742194800000003+0.6169670537999999j)
>>> z**2
(-0.02742194800000003+0.6169670537999999j)
```

the second must eventually do the first (plus whatever else it does.